# Lazarus под linux как добавить файл шрифта .fon

Tags: шрифты, lazarus

Под linux нет функции `AddFontResource`. Что может ее заменить?

Comment: Напомните, что такое Lazarus. Это Delphi на JVM?

Comment: Lazarus похож на Delphi, но это другая среда.